# Passing ObjectContext EF 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, savechanges, objectcontext

I have two classes Queries and ContactRepository.

```
    public static class Queries
    {
        public static Contact GetContactByName(CEntities context, string name)
        {
            return (from Contact c in context.Contacts
                    where c.Name == name
                    select c).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public class ContactRepository
    {
        private CEntities _dbContext;

        public ContactRepository()
        {
            _dbContext = new CEntities();
        }

        public void CreateContactAddress(string contactName, string address, string city, string state, string zip)
        {
            int contactId;
            ContactAddress ca = new ContactAddress();

            contactId = Queries.GetContactByName(_dbContext, contactName).Id;

            ca.ContactId = contactId;
            ca.Address = address
            ca.City = city;
            ca.State = state;
            ca.Zip = zip;

            _dbContext.ContactAddresses.AddObject(ca);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

When I call CreateContactAddress(), the SaveChanges() method crashes with the following error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering
>   for dependent operations. Dependencies
>   may exist due to foreign key
>   constraints, model requirements, or
>   store-generated values.

I can move the LINQ query into the CreateContactAddress() method itself, and everything works perfectly.  Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: A few comments unrelated to your problem - your `GetContactByName` can be re-written as `return context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == name);`. And since you use `FirstOrDefault`, you should also check whether the value is not null before you access the `Id` property. Regarding your code, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it as is, so I assume the problem lies elsewhere. As a starting point, how do you manage your context - that is I see where you create an instance, but where do you `Dispose` it?

Comment: I made the repository implement the IDisposable interface and use the repository with a using statement, but that still doesn't solve the problem.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: And you dispose of the context in the repository `Dispose` method? Are you able to reproduce the problem in a basic scenario? E.g. a console application that just creates a new instance of the repository and runs the `CreateContactAddress` method? (I did not manage to reproduce it.) If it fails in this simplest case, you should show your database table structure in order to try to find the problem.

Comment: I don't know why the error is happening but the error means that EF doesn't know what order to save objects in, generally caused by two object that reference each other. E.G. contact.AddressId and address.ContactId